# Is there an example that a probability distribution is having an increasing mean residual lifetime(IMRL) but not a Dreasing Failure Rate(DFR)

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, hazard, failure-rate

It is well known in risk theory that a random variable having a Decreasing Failure rate implies the Random Variable has an increasing mean residual lifetime. However, the converse is not true. Is there a counterexample?

A solution to a similar question regarding increasing failure rate and decreasing mean residual lifetime is appreciated